# The command dotnet run fails silently on Mac

Tags: macos, .net-core

Im trying to run a api application running on dotnetcore 2.2 on my mac. When I run `dotnet run`, the nuget packages are installed and the build is compiling. But after the build the process is shutting down. I have tried to set a breakpoint in Program.cs to see if it runs, but it doesnt. Anyone got a clue?

Comment: `dotnet run` doesn't expose the debugger hooks, so I would recommend trying out something like VS Code (with a `tasks.json` and a `launch.json` pair of files) and boot the app with F5. What does the shell output look like when you call `dotnet run`?

Comment: @JamieTaylor, sorry I did not respond here. That did work :)